# Displaying JSON as HTML with Handlebars (and without 'pre' tag)

Tags: jquery, html, json, handlebars.js

I am at a crossroads trying to figure out the easiest way to display "pretty" JSON on an HTML page using Handlebars. In the long run, I need to be able to access each line of the displayed JSON so - although it handles the prettiness - using a `pre` tag with the code below will not work.

```
$("#json").html(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));   //doesn't do what I need
```

Currently I have line-by-line Handlebars objects that look something like this:

```
<p class="indent-1">id: {{id}}</p>
<p class="indent-1">married: {{#if married}}true{{else}}false{{/if}}</p>
<p class="indent-1">name: {{name}}</p>
```

...but there are a lot of unnecessary paragraphs, classes, etc. in order for the JSON to *not* look like a hot mess. Plus, the JSON will not always include the same information, so I need it to be as dynamic as possible and not hard-coded like I have now.

Are there any plugins that might help me do this? Am I looking over something super simple?

Comment: One of the reasons why you can't do that automatically with Handlebars alone is that, by default, Handlebars doesn't allow recursion. If you're pretty-printing a flat object or an array, you could maybe make do with the 'each' helper, but if you have a deep structure, you need recursion :/ Recursion would be a great addition to Handlebars, in my opinion it's really lacking for not having that available.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty print seems like what you need https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/